# Java app startup with computer and be able to see system.out.println?

Tags: java, jar

I wrote a simple Java app which I have placed in the start up folder of my programs which makes the program starts when the computer starts up. what is the easiest way to make it open a command line or something which I can see the System.out.println results instead of just running in the background?

Comment: Are you talking about logging the details ?

Comment: now that you mention it that can be another option too, initially I was thinking about seeing the output as its running.

Comment: I have given the answer for you question below. You can find there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Log4j API for logging the details with the predefined outputs. It is far better then using SOP. Because it is light waighted and also very simple to configure the logs in the other files with the output format whichever you want to make.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/ Go to this url where you can find log4j api available.

Hope this work for you

Enjoy !!!

Answer (score 2):

You should familiarize yourself with logging frameworks such as [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) and [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j). Instead of using `System.out.println` you use some special API and the logging library redirects all messages to preconfigured appenders like console or file.

In your case you can configure your application to log on console while developing and switch to file when configuring an application to run from startup.

This won't really open a new command line window on startup, but instead it will store all messages to some predefined file on disk - which is actually even better.